# got bigg diff compare to print view and browser view

Tags: html, css

```
<div  style="z-index:1000px; position:absolute; bottom:180px; left:60PX; width:500px;%" >
```

In side this div i have message,

Text displaying fine in print view,(in top center place, my expected place)

but in the browser view the text displaying the below of the browser ,

i want to make it equal on print view as well as browser ,

How to do that

Comment: z-index should be a number and not have px at the end

Answer (score 2):

your code corrected, 2 problems

- There was a `%` misplaced within the style attribute
- z-index requires an integer value, but was appended with 'px' which makes it a string value [invalid]

---

```
<div style="z-index:1000; position:absolute; bottom:180px; left:60px; width:500px;" >
```